# Google Sheet formula for annualized returns - doubts

Tags: investing, compound-interest, spreadsheet

I'm trying to setup a calculator in google sheets where I calculate the future value of investing for example:

- a principal of 10.000
- into which I deposit 1.000 every month
- the investment doesn't give steady monthly returns but we can know an annualized average of 20% (say stocks or ETFs)

Would it be correct to use the formula:

> FV(rate, number_of_periods, payment_amount, [present_value], [end_or_beginning])

> FV(20, 12, 1000, -10000)

**The main doubt is also: when estimating the compounding of a volatile monthly market, should we consider the interest compounded monthly or yearly, given the example of an annualized 20% return?**

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it be correct to use the formula: FV(20, 12, 1000, -10000)

EDIT: both you and I overlooked percentage.  The first parameter should be `20%` not `20`.

Yes.  (I'd write the formula as `-FV(20%/12, 12, 1000, 10000)`.  Mathematically they are identical, and *I* interpret `-10000` as a negative amount of money.  However, maybe trained analysts use `-10000` and I'm the wrong one.)

> The main doubt is also if I should consider the interest compounded monthly or yearly?

That's up to you.  However, since it says "*annualized* average", I'd stick with 12 periods.

Comment: The formula as written returns an answer in the quintillions of dollars.

Comment: @glibdud see my edit.  (A single character can make all the difference...)

Comment: Hey thanks for sharing - I'm basically trying to replicate this thing here (https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/finance/calculators/compoundinterestcalculator.php) and if I change the parameter to monthly or yearly compound it makes a LOT of difference. I can't really grasp what's happening?

Comment: Shouldn't it be 20%/12? The formula knows nothing about the length of the periods involved; I think it expects rate per period, not annualized. Also, in your -FV formula you also need to flip the sign on the third argument.

Comment: @rudyStock I need more coffee. `-FV(20%, 12, 1000, 10000)` is for one $1000 contrib **per year** for **12 years**.  `-FV(20%/12, 12, 1000, 10000)` is for one contrib **per month** for **one year**.

Comment: @glibdud yeah, I need more coffee.  `=-FV(20%/12, 12, 1000, 10000) == $25,357.38`.

Comment: That's not mathematically identical to `FV(20%/12, 12, 1000, -10000)`.

Comment: @glibdud that must be why I never used it.  You should write your own answer.